# Facebook random metadata website

Tags: javascript, facebook

Hello im trying to make a random metadata website but om a little comfused on how the coding works. I think it uses **Javascript**.
Example : 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/p03MG.jpg

Comment: Hello im trying to figure out what you're referring to but om a little comfused

Comment: Check cinxp.com example

Comment: @Mangofett every time you reload site changes

Answer (score -1):

Yes you could use JavaScript for this. You can just put all the "img src values" into an array, then use the Math.random() function to generate a random number to address the "img src values" in the array whenever the page loads. You can then change the "src" attribute of the image to one of the values in the array.

**Here are the basics of what I mean (I won't hold your hand though):**

```
var yourImage = document.getElementById("yourImgElementsId");
var imgSrcArray = [imgSrc1, imgSrc2, imgSrc3, imgSrc4];
var randomNumber = Math.random() * (max - min) + min;

yourImage.src = imgSrcArray[randomNumber];
```

I would suggest learning JavaScript basics before attempting to finish this, then look at these sources when you're more confident:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random